# aws describe_instances returns incorrect values

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I wanted a quick and dirty to stop and start instances, so I penned the below, which completely gets bizzare answers from describe_instances and shows my instance to be running when it is in fact stopped and wont stop or start anything.

Anyone got a pointer to my obvious fault?

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'uuid'
require 'pp'


class InstanceManager
  def listInstances()
  ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:  "eu-west-1")
  resp = ec2.describe_instances()
    resp.reservations.each do |res|
     res.instances.each do |inst|
      iid = inst[:instance_id]
      istate = inst[:state].name
      puts "#{iid} #{istate}"
     end
    end
  end
  def stop(iid)
    ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:  "eu-west-1")
    inst = ec2.describe_instances(instance_ids: [iid]).reservations[0].instances[0]
    if ( inst[:state].name == "running" )
      puts "stopping #{iid}"
      res=ec2.stop_instances(dry_run: false, instance_ids: [iid],force: true)
      pp res
    else
      puts "#{iid} already stopped"
    end
    pp inst
  end
  def start(iid)
    ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:  "eu-west-1")
    inst = ec2.describe_instances(instance_ids: [iid]).reservations[0].instances[0]
    if ( inst[:state].name == "stopped" )
      pp inst
      puts "starting #{iid}"
      res=ec2.start_instances(dry_run: false, instance_ids: [iid],force: true)
      pp res
    else
      puts "#{iid} already started"
    end
    pp inst
  end
end

if __FILE__ ==$0
  z = InstanceManager.new
  z.listInstances()
#  z.stop("i-e122b106")
  z.start("i-e122b106")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are running into eventual consistency issues with the EC2 API. This is very common when working with Amazon EC2. When you issue a command, such as `#stop_instance`, the `#describe_instances` call will continue returning a status such as running for a period of time until the status changes. This can take multiple minutes.

Comment: So it would seem, I thought it might be dementia.